# Polymer iron-list dynamically adding items?

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to migrate some code from Polymer 0.5 to 1.x, this means moving from core-list to iron-list. However, I can not figure out an iron equivalent to how I was adding items to the core-list.

```
<core-list height="85">
<template>
<div class="{{ {selected: selected} | tokenList }}" style="padding:5px;"><paper-fab mini icon="arrow-forward" title="arrow-forward"></paper-fab> <!--{{index}}-->{{model.name}}</div>
</template>
</core-list>
```

which is called updated via...

```
document.querySelector('core-list').data = $.parseJSON('[{"name":"One"},{"name":"Two"}]');
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

---

Update : Jul-23-2015 12:20PM PST
@Zikes

Following the suggestion posted, I have the following.

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <iron-list items="[[myItems]]" as="item">
      <template>
        <div>[[item.name]]</div>
      </template>
    </iron-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is:'my-element',
      properties: {
        myItems: Array
      },
      addItem: function(item) {
        this.push('myItems', {name: item});
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

If this is setup right, how would I go about calling the addItem method from elsewhere?

---

Update : Jul-23-2015 1:58PM PST
@Zikes

Following is my current code. While I can manipulate the array, values added to it in the ready or addItem method are not being displayed.

```
<dom-module id="fnord-element">
  <template>
    <iron-list items="[[myItems]]" as="item">
      <template>
        <div class="item">[[item.name]]</div>
      </template>
    </iron-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is:'fnord-element',
      properties: {
        myItems: {
            type: Array,
            notify: true
        }
      },
      addItem: function(item) {
        //this.push("myItems", {"name":item});
        this.myItems=[{name:item}];
        alert(this.myItems[0].name);
        //alert(item);
      },
      ready: function() {
        //alert('fnord');
        this.myItems=[{name:"One"},{name:"Two"}];
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
<fnord-element id="fnord"></fnord-element>
<paper-button raised onclick="document.querySelector('#fnord').addItem('John Doe');">Test</paper-button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iron-list` uses the `items` property to generate its items, similar to `dom-repeat`.  What you can do is simply bind it to an Array in your component, like so:

```
<dom-module id="my-element>
  <template>
    <iron-list items="[[myItems]]">
      <template>
        <div>[[item]]</div>
      </template>
    </iron-list>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is:'my-element',
      properties: {
        myItems: Array
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Then, just follow [the rules for modifying an Array property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation) and you're all set!

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, see my updates to my question if you would be so kind, still not quite where I need to be with Polymer.

Comment: That's a fairly separate question since it doesn't directly address the `iron-list` usage.  The short answer is that Polymer methods become HTMLElement methods, so you can do `document.querySelector('my-element').addItem(...)`, even outside of the Polymer environment.

Comment: I understand, forgive my confusion. I was assuming that `querySelector` was no longer the preferred method since it seems to not work for me... `document.querySelector("my-element")` returns null and `document.querySelector("#my-element").addItem("test")` says it can't find the method addItem. So I'm clearly missing something...

Comment: It seems we're getting a few crossed wires.  Can you post a more complete example of how you're using your component, and how you want to go about adding items to it? It's okay if the code isn't functional, just something to show how you want it to work in the end.

Comment: I figured it out... due to lack of espresso I declared the dom-module, but didn't actually use it anywhere.

Comment: Haha, we've all been there. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Still missing something... I can modify the array, but the changes are not displayed. Do I need to refresh the iron-list somehow?

Comment: I'm not sure your `onclick` code will work, try changing it to `on-click` or `on-tap`.  Additionally, open your javascript console and run `document.querySelector('#fnord').addItem('John Doe');` to see if that works.

Comment: the code executes using onClick, I can see it triggering the alert(). Behavior is the same running the call from the console.

Comment: Marking as answered... looks like the issue is elsewhere in my app.